# How to show error messages Django

Tags: django, error-handling, model

I have this in my model

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True, error_messages={'unique': 'Name already exists'})
```

Then I have this form template

```
{% for field in form %}
    <span>{{ field.error }}</span>

    <label>{{ field.label_tag }}</label>

    <div> {{ field }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Whenever I put an existing name and click submit, the object does not add but no error message is displayed. How do you display the error message?

Comment: try `field.errors` instead of `field.error`

Comment: @AlexParamonov thanks it worked

Answer (score 4):

try get all the fields error in a form:

```
{% for field in form %}
  {{ field.errors|striptags }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need change this:

`{{field.error}}`

For this:

`{{field.errors}}`